# Dash 14.04 - permanently enable Files & Applications search

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I'm searching files and applications via Dash Home, but when I look for i.e. "OY" (it's a band/musician) Dash automatically disables 'Files' filter and I can't find what I'm used to find through Dash. It seems Dash 'intelligently' decides where it might find the desired search term...but in my case it's wrong too often.

Nooooow my question:
how can I lock the selected 'Categories' and 'Sources' in home lens?

Comment: What does  `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses always-search` tell you ?

Comment: Hi. The output is as i would expect  'TEST' ['applications.scope', 'music.scope', 'files.scope']

Comment: `['applications.scope', 'music.scope', 'files.scope']` (had difficulties handling mini markdown..)  
And I can watch the selected 'Categories' being automatically unselected when I alter my search term. Though I know that file exists. Dash just refuses to look for it.

Comment: Seems like your files scope is there but it's not working..... I'm used to finding files through command line, but i am not sure what's the issue with dash ....

Comment: Actually it's working for most of the files I search. But for some...not.